# Screen overlay has to be disabled everytime a new app is installed

Tags: android, screen, overlay, oneplustwo

I am using a OnePlus X phone and have recently updated the software to oxygenOS 3.1.3. After that i have been getting the screen overlay problem. I did my research and disabled going to the draw over other apps setting. But now everytime i install a new app and the app asks for permission the screen overlay dialog pops up and i have to go into safe mode and give permissions. Tired of doing it continuously everytime i install a new app!

Is there any way to set the screen overlay permanently? I do not have any cleaning apps as well as messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Fount it! The swipePad application created the problem.